# Default Shared Preferences : Source not found

Tags: android

I use Default Shared Preferences to save some data in them.
I have created a class to handle all this :

```
public class PreferencesHandler {

    private Context mContext;

    public PreferencesHandler (Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    public void setBoolean(String name, boolean value) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).edit()
                .putBoolean(name, value).commit();
    }

    public void setInt(String name, int value) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).edit()
                .putInt(name, value).commit();
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(String name, boolean defaultValue) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext)
                .getBoolean(name, defaultValue);
    }

    public int getInt(String name, int defaultValue) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).getInt(
                name, defaultValue);
    }   
}
```

How you see I created a Handler class for easier access.

Also I have a Methods class where all my methods are stored.

And in that class I have a method which uses this handler class :

```
public class Methods {

private Context mContext;

    public Methods(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

        public void process (PreferencesHandler pref, String prefName, int default) {
                int mInt= pref.getInt(prefName, default);

                //The rest doesn't matters
        }

}
```

I call this method in my activity class.

With the debugger I found out that the error is in the Handler, when it executes the return line, it opens the PreferenceManager.class with the text "Source not found".

It says that the JAR file android.jar has no source attachment.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Post logcat with full stacktrace.

Comment: It doesn't exit application just skips the step.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that the Activity that you use to call the constructor of `PreferencesHandler` gets destroyed, and then you try to use that `PreferencesHandler` in a new instance of that activity.

If this is the problem then this change in both constructors should fix that:

```
mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
```

As for the source code of PreferenceManager.class: use the Android SDK manager to install the Android sources and restart your IDE.

In Eclipse the Android SDK Manager can be found here: `Window -> Android SDK Manager`